# Including angular 2 with java actions and jsp

Tags: java, spring, angular, jsp

I am new to the angular 2 framework, recently I decided to work with this framework, after looking at this, many questions arose, my first attempt was to create an angular project with the angular cli, which worked, but when I decided to see How to include jsp files instead of html files I did not know how to do it, and I'm coming to you to find out if anyone has done it.
Since I use Spring and actions to send the information to jsp and display it, if someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 is a single page framework that does not need server side page rendering. Using JPS along with Angular2 does not provide any benefits. You best bet is to use HTML with Angular2 Javascript and make REST calls back to your Spring based server side code.